# Bulking up in maintainance calories

Tags: weight-loss, diet, bodybuilding, muscle-gain, sports

As an intermediate individual in fitness with decent bit of muscle definition and body fat, I was hoping to bulk up. However, I fear that with with a surplus I might end up gaining unnecessary fat while also gaining muscle. I was wondering for a guy with around 15 - 20% body fat, if it's possible to gain muscle with a maintenance calorie on a daily basis while occasionally on a  surplus of 5-10 percent. Given that I have appropriate protein, carbs and fat... could I actually loose body fat and gain muscle simultaneously?

*Edit:*
I actually heard that it is possible to recomp while on deficit or maintenance given that once is a beginner and have adequate macros such as the protein. To be more specific, when one is on maintenance  and is weightlifting that individual is trying to grow more muscle tissue however would need energy to do that hence would use the body fat as energy, hence the fat loss. However for the actual muscle gain he/she would need more **energy**. Should the maintenance calories and protein be enough for that extra energy or would you still need a surplus?

**Additional information about me:**

- Weight: 160 lbs
- Height: 5'7"
- Training: 3 days of week resistance training, 4 days of week cardio (10 minutes)

Comment: If the question is just "can I get muscular without getting fat?", the answer is absolutely yes. I feel like you're trying to ask something else, but I can't tell what. What's your current diet and lifting status?

Comment: All I am asking is can I bulk up without being on a caloric surplus. I am currently trying to be in a caloric surplus but I just don't seem to hit my daily surplus goals at all. As for lifting I am not lifting free weight but currently training with resistance bands. Currently training with 50 lbs of resistance and higher.

Comment: How and why don't you think you are hitting your food goals?

Comment: Tracking my macros using myfitnesspal

Comment: Okay, that's how you know. What do you think is the reason you are you not eating enough?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Well...initially tracking my calories I wasn't reaching my caloric maintenance goal. But after introducing some more meat into my diet now it seems like I am hitting the calories and protein however the fats are going off the charts. I just worry...if I don't maintain my fat levels I will be in trouble of gaining fat mass but at the same time i feel like macros don't really contribute to fat gain as long as the calories are in check so what exactly is it?

Comment: Good news! Dietary fat is not the cause of gaining fat mass. Relatedly, I recommend that people who want to gain weight and who are doing cardio 4x/week don't need to worry about getting fat until they actually do. Keep eating the meat and try to find challenging strength exercises.

Comment: Well actually I was thinking of gaining muscle and shredding my fat mass while in maintenance calories and also I do 2 days a week of cardio in the form of shadowboxing for 10 mins continuously. Just so I can keep up with my martial arts training and also burn some calories just in case.....
And that is along side my resistance training that i do 3 times a week for about an hour.

Comment: If you're skinny-fat and want to be more muscled but the same size then the recommendation is basically the same. Eat more protein and less of everything else and do the heaviest resistance training you can.

Comment: Yea I aware. I wouldn't say i am necessarily skinny fat as I do have a fair bit of muscle mass and a decent bit of fat mass around chest and belly. Although I was quite skinny fat months ago, I have been around a 6 week cut and just cardio training which allowed to loose a couple of pounds. But now I am trying to put some muscle in my body. However to do that, I would need protein and energy. But I free putting additional energy  might risk fat again. Hence decided to stay as close as I can to maintenance and follow the good old fashion one g per body weight  for protein.